# mysqlconnector python error: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm working on a Python project where I am querying a database multiple times with defined procedures and functions and the like. However, it seems as though I am only ever able to get the result from one prepared statement before I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", database="srd")
    cursor = db.cursor()

 # Column names
    cursor.execute("CALL show_columns(\"race\")")
    labels = cursor.fetchall()

# concat it into one line
    build = ""
    for labels in labels:
        build = build + labels[0] + " | "
    print(build)

# content
    cursor.execute("CALL select_all(\"race\")")
    results2 = cursor.fetchall()
    for result in results2:
        print(result)
    cursor.close()
```

and this is the output:

```
race_name | strengthASI | dexterityASI | constitutionASI | wisdomASI | intelligenceASI | charismaASI | flex_points | size | speed | abilities | proficiencies | has_subrace | 
// This part is correct output for printing the columns (the first query)


 File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 472, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now


mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2014 (HY000): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading over the documentation, I was incorrect in calling procedures using `cursor.execute("CALL ...")`.

The correct way to do this is by using the `cursor.callproc()` method, and retriving the data via `cursor.stored_results`.